# Travis CI - Run LWJGL Tests in Non-Headless Environment?

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl, travis-ci, headless

I'm trying to run some tests on Travis CI that require a server that's, err... *Not* headless. As you can tell, I know so little about the area I don't even know the right terminology to use.

The tests use LibGDX and LWJGL. They work fine on my desktop (Windows 8 and Ubuntu), but unsurprisingly fail in Travis CI:

```
Could not initialize class org.lwjgl.Sys
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:446)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:118)
```

Can I do anything with Travis CI to make it think it has a proper display? Even if this is not possible with Travis CI, is there a generic approach that I could perhaps take with another VM I have more control over?

Comment: Have you tried monitor imitation like `xvfb` as recommended in Travis CI docs: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/#Using-xvfb-to-Run-Tests-That-Require-GUI-(e.g.-a-Web-browser) ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It's not fixed my issues (LWJGL doesn't seem to notice the change), but it's certainly given me a lead to investigate.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with xvfb. In your travis.yml, add this:

```
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
```

You will have to install xvfb if you don't already have it. You may also have to install the other libs/packages needed by your tests on the VM (for e.g. for web app tests, you would need a browser).

Comment: @Deejay Just wanted to check with you again ... did you get a chance to try this out? What was the error if any?

Comment: I have same issue and try this answer.I still get error                                           Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setVSync(LwjglGraphics.java:446)
    Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: No display mode extension is available

Answer (score 2):

Starting a virtual framebuffer (xvfb) on Travis CI is not enough. If you need OpenGL > 1.4  you also need to install libgl1-mesa-swx11, libgl1-mesa-swx11-dev.

In my travis.yml I setup OpenGL and start xvfb with:

```
- sudo apt-get install -qq --force-yes mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-swx11 libgl1-mesa-swx11-dev xvfb  
- /sbin/start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile /tmp/custom_xvfb_99.pid --make-pidfile --background --exec /usr/bin/Xvfb -- :99 -screen 0 1400x900x24 -ac +extension GLX +render
```

the whole file is at:
https://github.com/mwohlf/pluto/blob/master/.travis.yml